# Sequelize query match all array values

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

DB : MYSQL

I've a data model which looks like this and it has many associate question table.

**Product Table** (This table has many questions relation )

| id | product_name | product_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 | 120 |
| 2 | product2 | 150 |
| 3 | product3 | 110 |
| 4 | product4 | 104 |
| 5 | product5 | 170 |
| 6 | product6 | 180 |

**Question table**

| id | question | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Q1 | Val1 |
| 2 | Q2 | Val2 |
| 3 | Q3 | Val3 |
| 4 | Q4 | Val4 |
| 5 | Q5 | Val5 |
| 6 | Q6 | Val6 |

let's say the product has total 3 questions and those are [3, 2, 1] -> (This indicates the id from question table)

Now I want to check if a product has all 3 questions. It need to match strictly.
Is there any way I can accomplish this?

I've tried Op.in and Op.and but those didn't work as expected. I'm new to sequelize and I would appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: is there anyone who can help me on this?

Comment: The tables don't seem to have a foreign key setup? I.e. the product table should have a column where the keys of the questions are stored. Or a seperate many2many table where all the product keys have a matching Questions key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the query after migrating to postgres since sequalize provide a few operators only for PG. So it was easy to fix after migration.